# Microsoft Reporting Services: Report Viewer save as button in toolbar does not download from Chrome

Tags: .net, google-chrome, download, report

The report viewer save as button has suddenly stopped working correctly from chrome, although it was working before. It still works from Firefox and Opera. When pressing the save as pdf button, it opens a new tab to download the file but then the tab just stays open without doing anything. If I refresh the new tab then the download happens. I also checked previous projects that I know for sure were working, to see if I missed something in my current project, but they have the same problem. I use ASP.NET web forms, .NET Framework version 4.6.1 and Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Webforms version 150.1404.0. Has anyone encounter this before, or has some kind of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. I was using a modal window with i-frame to load the page with the report viewer and Google stated that after Chrome version 83, they removed download in Sandboxed Iframes for security reasons and you have to add "allow-downloads" to the sandbox attributes list in order for it to work as stated here:
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280